# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Builder

Tags: java, android

I am running a sample to upload and download a file on google drive and it  crashes in following function:

```
private Drive getDriveService(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
    return new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
        new GsonFactory(), credential).build(); 
}
```

and the Logcat says:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Builder
```

Any sort of help will be appreciated.
For reference I am using [this sample](https://github.com/wdziemia/Drive-Utility).

Comment: Have you imported all the required `jar` for Google Drive?

Comment: Yes I imported all **jars** and **google-play-services.lib** too.

Comment: So, you followed this http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html, right? Another useful reference is https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started.

Comment: Yes I followed both of these links but still I was unable to run this sample.

Comment: check java build path of the project. Is that lib checked in "Order and export" tab?

Comment: No! they are unchecked.